Python, pandas Когда вывожу весь Series, значения меняются на подобные 2.066726e+04
Когда вывожу Series таким образом значения заменяются на подобные 2.066726e+04
tot_inc

14585    2.066726e+04
13006    2.120528e+04
16174    2.136765e+04
1598     2.169510e+04
14276    2.189561e+04
10881    2.247276e+04
18509    2.384471e+04
9070     2.445767e+04
10068    2.522789e+04
Name: total_income, dtype: float64

При этом когда использую метод .head(), значения нормальные
tot_inc.head()

14585    20667.263793
13006    21205.280566
16174    21367.648356
1598     21695.101789
14276    21895.614355
Name: total_income, dtype: float64

В задаче необходимо получить срез значений
income_min = df['total_income'].min()
income_mean = df['total_income'].mean()

tot_inc = df['total_income']
tot_inc = tot_inc.sort_values()
pt1 = tot_inc.loc[income_min : income_mean]
pt1

после выполнения кода появляется "KeyError 20667.26379327158"
(income_min)

То, что вы хотите сделать, делается по-другому:
pt1 = tot_inc.loc[(income_min<=tot_inc) & (tot_inc<=income_mean)]

.loc работает с индексом, а вы выбираете по значениям.
Ну и вывод данных - это вообще отдельный вопрос, формат вывода в Pandas настраивается в опциях вывода.
